# Beginner Doctrine Entity Relationship Assistance Needed

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm new to doctrine and having difficulty trying to set up my first Entity Relationships/Associations.

I'm wanting the following two tables:

```
Kitchen
- ID
- Name
- Description
- MainImage

KitchenImage
- ID
- KitchenID (ref Kitchen.ID)
- Image
```

Each kitchen will have a main photo along with a load of sub photos.

Here are my two doctrine files at the moment (removed get and setters for formatting):

**Kitchen**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="kitchen")
 */
class Kitchen
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $image;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="KitchenImage", mappedBy="kitchen")
     */
    protected $images;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->images = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

**Kitchen_Image**

```
/**
 * KitchenImage
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="kitchen_image")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class KitchenImage
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $image;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Kitchen", inversedBy="images")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="kitchen_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $kitchen;
}
```

**PHP function:**

```
public function createAction()
    {
        $kitchen = new Kitchen();
        $kitchen->setName('Example Kitchen');
        $kitchen->setDescription('Big amount of text to go here...');
        $kitchen->setImage('front-image.jpg');

        $image1 = new KitchenImage();
        $image1->setImage('1.jpg');

        $image2 = new KitchenImage();
        $image2->setImage('2.jpg');

        $kitchen->addImage($image1);
        $kitchen->addImage($image2);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($kitchen);
        $em->flush();

        return new Response('success');
    }
```

**Error Response**

```
A new entity was found through the relationship 'PWD\WebsiteBundle\Entity\Kitchen#images' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: PWD\WebsiteBundle\Entity\KitchenImage@0000000009670754000000003a9b3dc9. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'PWD\WebsiteBundle\Entity\KitchenImage#__toString()' to get a clue.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` => What is the problem/error?

Comment: @cheeseemacfly Updated question to include error and function.

Comment: Have you tried to change `@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Kitchen", inversedBy="images")` to `@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Kitchen", inversedBy="images",cascade={"persist"})`? Could it solve the issue the way you want it to be solved?

Comment: @cheesemacfly gets the same error.

Comment: My bad, it should be on the `$image` propertie: `@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="KitchenImage", mappedBy="kitchen",cascade={"persist"})`

Comment: @cheesemacfly I get this - [Semantical Error] Couldn't find constant cascade, property PWD\WebsiteBundle\Entity\Kitchen::$images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace this piece of code:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($kitchen);
$em->flush();
```

With this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($image1);
$em->persist($image2);
$em->persist($kitchen);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: This creates a record thanks. However, kitchen_id is always null?

Comment: after `flush()` you can get the kitchen id with `$kitchen->getId();`. Please accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Never mind, I wasn't setting the kitchen with $kitchen->setKitchen()